# 2006 inherited iMac privileges issue

Tags: mac, privileges, imac

I recently got my grandpa's old iMac from 2006. I made my account, made it an admin, and deleted his. I put 10.5.1 on it since it had 10.4 before. Now when I try to get the update, it says I don't have sufficient privileges. I don't know why this would be. I have 512Mb ram if that has anything to do with it. I'm also having other issues with privileges, like writing to and partitioning my external hard drive.

Comment: Have you tried repairing permissions since the install?  If software update is failing, have you tried downloading the combo update and installing that?

Comment: Fixed it. Something went wrong during the 10.5 install and I had to get it erase installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something had gone wrong during the installation of the new OS. Had to get an erase install.